# Post a form with only some fields

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

In my HTML/PHP application I have a simple form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
    <input type="text" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
    <input type="text" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">

    <button type="submit" name="submitform" class="btn btn-success" value="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Then, in another part of the page I have a standard button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
```

When the user presses this button, the desired behavior is to mimic the same behavior of posting the form using the submit button, but:

1. include specific fields only (let's say `vehicle2`)
2. set a given value for them

Example, for simplicity I'm using a single field:

```
function updateForm(id, value)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "samepage.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({submitform: "save", id: value}),
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.error(request, status, error);
        }
    });     
}
```

so I can call it as:

```
updateForm("vehicle2", "Plane");
```

Here my PHP code of the page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitform'])) {
    switch ($_POST["submitform"]) {
        case "save":
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == 'submitform') continue;
                $sql_update = 'UPDATE settings SET value="' . $value . '" WHERE id=' . $key;
                $db->exec($sql_update);
            }
            break;
    }
}
?>

HTML follows...
```

But it returns an error about the json content:

> parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data

Is my approach wrong?

Comment: What is the return data ?

Comment: is it when responding or requesting ?

Comment: @SandrinJoy, is in the "error" branch, so when responding

Comment: what is samepage.php ? And how the data post looks like in the dev tools ?

Comment: so where is your return data?

Comment: @executable, I want to mimc the post like the submit button, I mean reloading the page after post. I don't need an answer (in fact the code above will return the whole html page).

Comment: I think you should add `event.preventDefault();` in the ajax function

Comment: @executable, "samepage.php" is the *same page* where these scripts are.

Comment: You are expecting to have json data as return data

Comment: @executable, ok that my fault. But how to reload the page (like the actual submit button) instead of waiting for an answer?

Comment: What do you mean waiting ? You're using ajax (asynchronous HTTP ). I don't get the point of reloading the page if you're using Ajax

Comment: @executable, for this reason I asked if "this is the right approach". As said, I just want to submit the form like the submit button does, but posting only some fields with a given value. If my approach is wrong, please feel free to propose the correct one.

Comment: While I sense what you're wanting to do here I also sense that this will provide your users with a terrible experience.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, the actual scenario would make more sense. There is a form (a long table) that provides the user a lot of settings (parameters). Then, there are few buttons that will set some of them to specific values. Hence the request to maintain the same user experience of saving the whole form, while updating only few of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct code you sended (mostly the ajax request) :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitform'])) {
    switch ($_POST["submitform"]) {
        case "save":
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == 'submitform') continue;
                $sql_update = 'UPDATE settings SET value="' . $value . '" WHERE id=' . $key;
                $db->exec($sql_update);
            }
            break;
    }
}
?>
<script>
function updateForm(id, value)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "samepage.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {submitform: "save", id: value},
        success: function (result) {
            // reload the page ?
            //location.reload();
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.error(request, status, error);
        }
    });
}
</script>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
    <input type="text" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
    <input type="text" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
    <button type="submit" name="submitform" class="btn btn-success" value="save">Save</button>
</form>
<button onclick="updateForm('vehicle2', 'Plane');" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
```

**EDIT:**

Or you can simply add a form :

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="vehicle2" value="Plane">
    <button type="submit" name="submitform" class="btn btn-success" value="save">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Reloading the page is not a solution because is a GET request. Furthermore I added a `die()` inside the `if (isset($_POST['submitform']))` but even the ajax result contains all the HTML - it seems the "hidden" code of the submit button is quite different from this.